# making a picturebox not move when another is created

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

im trying to make a bullet like system i want a picture box that will be created when a button is clicked and then that picture box will start moving up but when i click the button the picturebox will go from its position to its start position here's my code

### -------here's my complete code @ visual vincent

```
Public Class Form1

Dim ind As New List(Of Integer)
Dim nums As ArrayList
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim add As Integer
Dim Particles As New List(Of PictureBox)

Dim dose As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    For x = 0 To 100


        Dim PBox As New PictureBox
        Particles.Add(PBox)
        Particles(x).Top = 600
        Particles(x).Left = rnd.Next(20, 30)
        Particles(x).BackColor = Color.Blue
        Particles(x).Width = 2
        Particles(x).Height = 2
        Me.Controls.Add(Particles(index))



    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub




Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    add += 1

    Particles.Item(add).Top -= rnd.Next(4)

    If add >= 99 Then
        add = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

end class

--

### ----just paste it in to vs

i would like all of them to move at the same time

Comment: You have only one particle. Anything you do will effect it. You need to create a seperate particle each time and control it seperatly.

Comment: Exactly what is going slow? May I get a link to your project so that I can test it out? Because right now you're changing each particle on it's own. So each time your timer tics it will change one particle, then the next one, and after that the next one, etc... Also, just a suggestion: Remove the 'index' variable and use the 'x' variable instead, inside the loop. :)

Comment: heres the link it should work http://www.mediafire.com/download/61fky2cb8uk8afu/WindowsApplication56.vbproj

Comment: "----just paste it in to vs". -Ok :D

Comment: But do you want all particles to move at the same time? Or...?

Comment: yeah i want all of them to move at the same time but dont know how

Comment: Fixed, see my edit :). Please note that "For x = 0 To 100" creates 101 particles instead of 100. To make it 100 change "To 100" to "To 99".

Comment: ok when i create 1,000 picture boxes it really get's slow so how would i make instead of picture boxes could i make it rectangles so there's not as much over head like system.graphics.fillrectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a List:

Dim Particles As New List(Of PictureBox).

---

As an answer to your comment:

I believe this should work, but I'm not 100% sure.

First declare the list in your form class:

```
Dim Particles As New List(Of PictureBox) From {New PictureBox, New PictureBox, New PictureBox} 'Three particles
```

Then set their properties (i.e in the Form1_Load):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '(0) is the index of your first particle. They usually start at 0 and goes up.
    Particles(0).BackColor = Color.Black
    Particles(0).Top = 600
    Particles(0).Left = 10
    Particles(0).Width = 6
    Particles(0).Height = 6
    Particles(0).Visible = True

    Particles(1).BackColor = <your color>
    Particles(1).Top = <your top>
    Particles(1).Left = <your left>
    Particles(1).Width = <your width>
    Particles(1).Height = <your height>
    Particles(1).Visible = True

    Particles(2).BackColor = <your color>
    Particles(2).Top = <your top>
    Particles(2).Left = <your left>
    Particles(2).Width = <your width>
    Particles(2).Height = <your height>
    Particles(2).Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Controls.Add(Particles(0))
    Particles(0).Top = 600
    Controls.Add(Particles(1))
    Particles(1).Top = <your top>
    Controls.Add(Particles(2))
    Particles(2).Top = <your top>
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Particles(0).Top -= 3
    Particles(1).Top -= <your value>
    Particles(2).Top -= <your value>
End Sub
```

Or just move Particles(1) and/or Particles(2) to a new timer if you'd like it to start sooner, go faster, etc.

---

To add 100 Particles, put this For loop on top in Form1_Load:

```
Dim Particles As New List(Of PictureBox)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For x = 1 To 100
        Dim PBox As New PictureBox
        Particles.Add(PBox)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

In the timer, do:

```
For x = 0 To 100
    Particles.Item(x).Top -= rnd.Next(4)
Next
```

Comment: im new to vb so how would you do that

Comment: thanks now what if i wanted to make like 100 particles would i add more particles to the list or is there a more efficient way

Comment: To add a few more particles, keep adding to the list... But to add 100 particles, check my edit.

Comment: look at the bottom of my question